# Is it possible to see a history of email addresses to which an email was sent to, by Amazon SES?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have a subscription form that, when filled, sends an email using Amazon SES & stores user info in my database.

The database has not been working in recent weeks, although mail delivery has worked.

Since my storage mechanism has failed, can SES provide me with a history of email addresses to which an email was sent to?

Comment: Do you have any configuration sets i.e. https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/ses/home?region=eu-west-1#/configuration-sets?

Comment: no, I don't have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since my storage mechanism has failed, can SES provide me with a history of email addresses to which an email was sent to?

No unfortunately, unless you previously configured it to do so.

Checking anything at a granular level within SES - including email sending/delivery - can only be done using [event publishing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/monitor-using-event-publishing.html).

Also, event publishing cannot be backdated so if you enable it now, it will also only work for emails sent from this point onwards.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but I guess it's still an answer. Thanks. I'll take a look at event publishing to use from here on out.

Comment: @carl Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, hope you get it sorted and it doesn't happen again.